# Get date from substring in where clause of a sql select *EDITED*

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, substring

I have a date stored within a text field with other text.  Why didn't they just put this in a date field? I have no idea, but I do not have the power to change it now.  Elsewhere in the code, I am doing this to get the records where this date is in a certain range. It works fine.

```
For Each i As InventoryItem In inventoryList
  index = i.Notes.IndexOf("on {") + 4
  scanned_dt = i.Notes.Substring(index, i.Notes.Length - index - 1)
  If Date.Parse(scanned_dt) >= startDate And Date.Parse(scanned_dt) <= endDate Then
    ...
```

I am now trying to get a total of items for a certain date range.
This sql statement works to get the total for all dates.  How can I update the Where clause to only count the items where i.Notes contains a date between `startDate` and `endDate`

```
Dim sql As String = "Select COUNT(inv_PartNum) from lester.inventory i join lester.vendor v on v.vendor_ID = i.vendor_ID Where v.vendor_Name = '" + vendorName + "' AND i.inv_Desc LIKE '%" + size + "%'"
```

****EDITED****
I came up with this sql select statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.inv_PartNum) FROM cdms.lester.inventory AS I
join CDMS.lester.vendor AS v on v.vendor_ID = i.vendor_ID Where v.vendor_Name = 'JVE-285' 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,
SUBSTRING(i.inv_Notes, CharIndex('on {', i.inv_Notes)+4, len(i.inv_Notes)-(CharIndex('on {', i.inv_Notes) + 4)
),101) BETWEEN '01-01-2011' AND '04-04-2011'
```

But I am getting this error:
**The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.**

In trying to figure it out I created the following sql select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT i.inv_Notes, 
CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(i.inv_Notes, CharIndex('on {',i.inv_Notes)+4,LEN(i.inv_Notes)-(CharIndex('on {', i.inv_Notes) + 4)),101) AS d
FROM cdms.lester.inventory AS i
join CDMS.lester.vendor AS v ON v.vendor_ID = i.vendor_ID WHERE v.vendor_Name = 'JVE-285') AS s
```

My inv_Notes column contains a string like "Assigned to Tool Trailer {JVE-285} on {4/8/2011}"

When I run the query as shown above, I get my inv_Notes column along with the date column. The dates all show in this format "2011-04-08 00:00:00.000" and no errors are thrown.

However as soon as I add a WHERE clause, I get the error: **The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.**

I've tried formatting the date every which way, but always get the error...

```
WHERE s.d > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-1-1', 101)

WHERE s.d < GetDate()

WHERE s.d > '20110101'

WHERE s.d >= '2011-01-01'

WHERE s.d >= '01-01-2011'

WHERE s.d > '01/01/2011'
```

**EDIT**
I've also tried 
`WHERE s.d IS NOT NULL`
and get the same error. This obviously isn't working the way I think it's working b/c at the point of the WHERE, the conversion should have already successfully happened.

**SOLUTION**
Got this working

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT i.inv_Notes,
SUBSTRING(i.inv_Notes, CharIndex('} on {',i.inv_Notes)+6,LEN(i.inv_Notes)-(CharIndex('} on {', i.inv_Notes) + 6))
AS d
FROM cdms.lester.inventory AS i
join CDMS.lester.vendor AS v ON v.vendor_ID = i.vendor_ID WHERE v.vendor_Name = 'JVE-285') AS s
WHERE PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.d, '/', '.'), 1)+
RIGHT('00'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.d, '/', '.'), 3),2)+
RIGHT('00'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(s.d, '/', '.'),2),2) BETWEEN '20110407' AND '20110409'
```

I tried to cast that to int and do an integer comparison but then I get an error.  Figured out that the problem was that some of the inv_Notes fields contain data like "Item Added {3/11/2011}" None of those meet the conditions for the inner select, so in my mind if it's not selected in the inner select, it shouldn't be a problem for the condition of the outer select.  However, it was trying to cast 2011{311 to int and throwing an error.  I'm sure it was trying to cast that to date and that's why I had the previous problems.

Comment: What  database are you using? I would recoment writting a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something similar to this WHERE clause into your statement:

```
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(Notes, CHARINDEX(Notes, 'on {') + 4, Length?) AS Date) BETWEEN StartDate And EndDate
```

The idea been that you extract the relevant part of the string by combining the SubString and CharIndex methods, and then convert this expression to a date format so that it can be used with the Between Operator.

Best of Luck

Part 2 Update:

As you have been able to select the date but not use it in the where clause, I suggest using it as a select statement and then wrapping this in another statement e.g:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(Notes, CHARINDEX(Notes, 'on {') + 4, Length?) AS Date) AS dtmNotes)
WHERE dtmNotes BETWEEN Start And End
```

This is just to illustrate, but include the whole of your first select statement in the wrapping.

Comment: Came up with same solution, but am getting an error.  See above edit.

Comment: Nope. I've tried that way too, but just did it again for good measure. No luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that is what I have.  The above WHERE statements are added to the last line on the outside band of the nested SELECT.  That's what I just can't figure out. It's doing the substring cast/convert (I've tried both ways) without error.

Comment: In your select statement, is the date aligned to the left or right of the field, as by default, numerics & dates are right aligned, if it is still showing on the left then we can assume it is still represneted as a string and the cast/convert isn't yet working.

Comment: It is left aligned.  However if I add to the select a field from my table which is stored as datetime, it is also left aligned.

Comment: That's a little weird, as in all cases I can remember, true dates are right aligned (perhaps that's from older versions) All I can think now is to try getting your date as a number in YYYYMMDD format like 20111005 and then carry out the between on the numeric values instead.

Comment: Edited my question to include final solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah cool, I see the numeric approach helped towards the answer. Your Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

assuming that the table with the embedded date is called **InventoryList** and the column is called **inv_Notes**

```
SELECT *
FROM InventoryList i
WHERE

CAST(
substring(
i.inv_Notes,
patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)  +4,
patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}%',i.inv_Notes)-patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)
) as Datetime)

BETWEEN '12/1/2011' AND '12/23/2011
```

**EDIT: More restrictive looking for a "9/9999}" pattern**

```
SELECT *
FROM InventoryList i
WHERE

CAST(
substring(
i.inv_Notes,
patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)  +4,
patindex('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}%',i.inv_Notes)-patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)
) as Datetime)

BETWEEN '12/1/2011' AND '12/23/2011
```

Comment: I get the same error.  If I do `SELECT  CAST(
substring(
i.inv_Notes,
patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)  +4,
patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}%',i.inv_Notes)-patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes)
) as Datetime) FROM lester.inventory AS i` I get the datetime in a column with no error, just like my version.

Comment: Is the pattern 'on {' always consistent? Meaning is it always present? Is it always lowercase?

Comment: What happens when you add this where clause to your above select query - WHERE (patindex('%on {%',i.inv_Notes) <> 0) 
AND (patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}%',i.inv_Notes) <> 0)

Comment: Yes, the pattern is always consistent. If I add that "WHERE" clause, it runs just the same as if it wasn't there.  The CAST appears to work just fine b/c I get the column of datetimes. When I have the cast in the select the dates appear as "2011-04-08 00:00:00.000" When I have just the substring part in the select without the cast, it returns "4/8/2011"

Comment: Okay the is it possilve the "vendor" portion of the description can be formatted as {Vendor-9999} meaning there are four digits followed by a '}'. If so then try using a more restrictive pattern such as patindex('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}%',i.inv_Notes) this way it should only look for and match this pattern '9/9999}'

Comment: In all current cases the vendor portion is "JVE-999" (3 digits) or is all chars, but I can't say in the future that it may not go to 4 digits.